# Draw a black line in java

Tags: java

Below is the project where I'm working on.

The problem is in the method Plotline(). This method takes three variables and has to use these variables to draw a black line which should not go beyond the width and the length of the JLable.

Im trying to do it in a for loop but i don't know how to make de relation between variables and the objects in this project.

The project runs through another class that is NewJFrame.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Image {
  private JLabel          label;
  private BufferedImage   image;
  private Color           color;
  private Color[][]       color_array;
  private Color[][]       temp_array;

public Image(JLabel _label, Color _color)
{
    label = _label;
    image           = new bufferedImage(label.getHeight(),label.getWidth(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    color_array     = new Color[label.getWidth()][label.getHeight()];       
    color = _color;
    Background();
    Draw();
}

public void Background()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < color_array.length ; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < color_array[i].length; j++)
            color_array[i][j] = color;

}
public void Plotline(int _x1, int _x2, int _y)
{
    Color tmp_color = new Color(0);
    for(int i=0; i <color_array.length-1; i++){
        Draw();
    }

}

public void Draw()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < color_array.length ; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < color_array.length; j++)
            image.setRGB(i, j, color_array[i][j].getRGB());
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    label.repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: You already asked a very similar question on Stack Overflow and it was closed for its low quality. This kind of questions is off topic on Programmers.SE.

Comment: can upls  tell me how to improve the quality of my question?

Comment: i`ve edited this topic. is this now ok?

Comment: Ok, this looks better, people now can at least see what you actually tried to do. I corected the formatting slightly & flagged the question for moderator attention. Hopefully they can somehow reopen and migrate to Stack Overflow (since this is only on topi over there at SO)

Comment: how can then the onhold goes off? how can i inform other people who have put a - sign on my question?

Comment: It would be better to fix the version on Stack Overflow and get that one reopened rather than migrating this question.

Comment: @user2841780 as ChrisF suggests, copy those edits to your question on Stack Overflow. There are links at each question for "reopen" or "flag". (You may not see them because some functionality requires higher rep). If you edit it I will try to propose reopening or flag for moderator attention. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: hi, can sb tel me pls why i dont get any reply on this question? is the question dead or is this just normal te get no answer sometimes?

Answer (score 2):

You are right. There is no connection between your variables in different methods. They should connect via some parameter or class variable. 
Actually it shouldn't be such complicated. One method is quite enough to draw your line. Here is fixed code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello, World!");
        frame.add(label);

        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        new Image(label, Color.BLACK).Plotline(10, 90, 100);
        frame.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        new Test();
    }
}

// /
class Image {
    private JLabel label;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Color color;
    private Color[][] color_array;
    private Color[][] temp_array;

    public Image(JLabel _label, Color _color) {
        label = _label;
        image = new BufferedImage(label.getHeight(), label.getWidth(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        color_array = new Color[label.getWidth()][label.getHeight()];
        color = _color;
        Background();
    }

    public void Background() {
        for (int i = 0; i < color_array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < color_array[i].length; j++) {
                color_array[i][j] = color;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Plotline(int _x1, int _x2, int _y) {
        int black_color = new Color(0).getRGB();
        for (int i = _x1; i < color_array.length - 1 && i < _x2; i++) {
            if (_y >= 0 && _y < color_array[i].length)
                image.setRGB(i, _y, black_color);
        }
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
        label.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. But i thought since 'color_array' is within the class Image, it is called a class variable. Isn`t that right?

Comment: It is right. And you have these variables. You just didn't use them. You made it right in the Background method. But your Draw and PlotLine do not use them. Especially for changes to draw the line.